# How the expression of multiline string in PHP is better?

Tags: php, string, multiline

If I want to say

```
Hello
World
```

, would recommend to use `'` (Apostrophe) or `"` (Quotation mark)?
Example:

```
<?php
$apostrophe = 'Hello' . "\n" . 'World!';

$quotation_mark = "Hello\nWorld!";

$newline = 'Hello
World!';

echo (($apostrophe == $quotation_mark) && ($apostrophe == $newline));
```

Output: `1` (True)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Comment: Whatever you like really, just try to avoid mixing different styles all over the code. Quotes look cleaner to me. There might be some overhead from concatenation, but it is most likely negligible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you think about this

```
$text = 'Hello' . PHP_EOL
      . 'World!';
```

In my opinion this is well readable
The difference between the quotatation marks is easy. A String with the double quotatation mark is parsed for variables and special values, the other not.